# Rectangle using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am new to HTML, CSS and bootstrap and trying to make a page something like this.

```
..............................................................................................................................................................

                                     Header
..............................................................................................................................................................
```

And after this Header I need a rectangle in my page with some text and a button.

Specification I need to follow for this rectangle are as follows:

Here is my code:

```css
.rectangle {
  width: 632px;
  height: 269px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid 1px #e0e0e0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
}

.Find-your-number {
  width: 468px;
  height: 23px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 1.28;
  letter-spacing: -0.03px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333333;
}

.btn-bg {
  width: 303px;
  height: 48px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f9c940;
}

.open {
  width: 291px;
  height: 54px;
  font-size: 49px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 1.1;
  letter-spacing: -0.8px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333333;
  padding-top: 5%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 pt-md-5 text-center">
      <div class="rectangle">
        <p class="open">Open here</p>
        <p class="find-your-number">Find your number</p>
        <button class="btn-bg">Start</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This rectangle should be at `250px` from top and `196px` from side. How can I get it?
As of now I am getting rectangle towards a bit left side of page.

Also, text inside rectangle also not taking proper font size and alignment  as mentioned in CSS. How can I correct it?

Comment: I'm thinking you might not know what Bootstrap is for. You should go read around of docs on Bootstrap first to see what they support and what it's not capable of.

Comment: I know I just started it. But it would be great help if  you can give me a solution for  this and explain it

Comment: `margin:250px 196px 0;` ? can you clarify ?  what are these line of dots and the word header have to do with your *rectangle* issue ?

Comment: nothing ...I just explained my page  here that's it

Comment: Please keep in mind, if one of the answers works for you, please mark them as the answer to help other peeps in the community to find their solution easier if they facing the same issue. You can do this by using grey marks (tick) beside answers (you can only choose one), for more information please read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 0):

with or without pingendo.com you should try this (to all devices)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="theme.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="py-5">
    <div class="container m-0 px-0 col-12" style="border-top: 3px dotted blue;border-bottom: 3px dotted blue;">
      <div class="row px-0 py-5 border-top border-bottom shadow-sm">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center col-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col xl-12">generic header for : xs sm md lg and xl</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you please explain me this code. I didn't got much.

Comment: will it be same as above mentioned css?

Comment: nps this is not what I want

Comment: It is just giving two borders. I want rectangle at center

Comment: well ,bootstrap was design to build responsive 100% stuff: tat look similary or adapt to every screen.

Comment: if you need entirely a rectangle delete that other border style and replace them with border: 3px dotted blue;

Comment: I just added the new code snippet that covers the bootstrap approach you can use it as well also.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what from the picture that you shared, you can do it manually with pure CSS or by using bootstrap. I chose the pure CSS approach, so for this cause you will need to use `flexbox` and the related attributes with it such `align-items` and `justify-contents` and set them to `center` to achieve the center align.
There are some other approaches to achieve this like using `table` and `vertical-align` and some other.

```css
.container{
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  width: 632px;
  height: 269px;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid 1px #e0e0e0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  display: ms-flexbox;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box > .box-title {
  font-size: 49px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 1.1;
  letter-spacing: -0.8px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333333;
  padding-top: 5%;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.box > .box-description {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 1.28;
  letter-spacing: -0.03px;
  color: #333333;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.box > .box-action > button {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 303px;
  height: 48px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f9c940;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="box-title">
          Check-in here
        </div>
        <div class="box-description">
          <p>Find your reservation and collect your room keys</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box-action">
          <button>start</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**

*Implementation with bootstrap*

In this approach, you just need to visit [bootstrap website](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/) and then add the related CDNs to your project, then you have to just add `d-flex`, `align-items-center`, and `justify-content-center` to the main container of your page.

```css
.box > .box-title {
  font-size: 49px;
}

.box > .box-description {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.box > .box-action > button {
  width: 303px;
  height: 48px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #f9c940;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="container my-5 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <div class="box border rounded p-5 text-center">
        <div class="box-title">
          Check-in here
        </div>
        <div class="box-description">
          <p>Find your reservation and collect your room keys</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box-action">
          <button>start</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: in your solution how to remove this grey area behind?

Comment: and keep rectangle as per css mentioned above and in center

Comment: so here we go, I just made some change due to your request, for this purpose to make it responsive and keep it work with custom height, width and other kinds of stuff, you should add another flexbox attribute to the box class itself that create your rectangle, and maintain the growth of each his child element with flex itself and max-width

Comment: @user9966539
also, keep in mind, you should avoid giving height and width to the elements such header and texts, and even silly paddings to destroy your whole card structure.

Comment: Thanks It worked but  just want to know how can I have samething purely in bootstrap

Comment: @user9966539 Yeah, sure I just added new snippet that contains the bootstrap approach also!